# I still cannot view story board in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Ive been running through forums and still can't find a fix. is there a library I'm missing? If there is a forum with an answer somewhere please let me know. Thanks.

Edit:

Im using mac, version 9.5.1 build 3 Xamarin studio

the error message is: there was a problem rendering this document. Then it gives me an option to view in Xcode.

If I am missing any other details please let me know. I was able to view it once and I have no idea what I did then the program crashed and I cannot view it again. Im just trying to view it as I open the project to add a user interface.

Thanks again

Comment: You haven't included ANY meaningful information that would allow us to help you.  Are you using Mac or Windows?  Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio?  Do you get any error messages?  Are you trying to create a new storyboard, or edit an existing one?  What happens when you try to view one?  Are you unable to open the Designer, or is this a problem at runtime?

Comment: Sorry man just a bit frustrated, I have updated my question. Please ask if there is something I missed I tend to over look basic things.